# Migrating ant maven jboss

Tags: maven, jboss, nexus

I am currently migrating from ant script to maven build.  Target server is JBOSS 5.2.1 eap.  The existing Ant script puts the implemented server jars (and others) on the classpath.  JBOSS provides maven libs for EAP 6, but not prior.  It seems the best choice is to place these jars into a local Nexus, but there are MANY jars on the classpath (over 190 in the servers lib directory).  I am looking for advice on how to structure (GAV coordinates) and upload the many jars to a local nexus (oss) repository without having a maven entry for EACH jar file in the pom.  Is there a best strategy?

Comment: why are you packaging a j2ee app as separate jars and not deploying as an *.ear archive?

Comment: take a look in this https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-